# Animate SVG on scroll

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

I'm animating an SVG line based on my scroll position. It works but the FPS is really low and the animation itself is laggy. I pretty sure it's my native Javascript skills that are screwing things up, but I don't know how to solve it.

I made a quick and dirty JSbin replica of what I currently have on the actual website;

http://jsbin.com/vigaqoxiru/edit?html,css,js,output

```
window.requestAnimationFrame = window.requestAnimationFrame || window.mozRequestAnimationFrame || window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame || window.msRequestAnimationFrame || function(f){setTimeout(f, 1000/60)}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    Timeline();
});

function Timeline() {
    requestAnimationFrame(animateLine)

    function convertRange( value, r1, r2 ) { 
         return ( value - r1[ 0 ] ) * ( r2[ 1 ] - r2[ 0 ] ) / ( r1[ 1 ] - r1[ 0 ] ) + r2[ 0 ];
    }

    function animateLine() {
        var offset = window.scrollY;
        var wheight = window.innerHeight;
        var timeline = document.querySelector(".Approach--steps");
        var theight = timeline.getBoundingClientRect().top - wheight;

        if (theight < 0) {
            var timelineMin = timeline.offsetHeight;
            var objectMin = timeline.offsetTop;
            var objectMax = timeline.offsetTop + timeline.offsetHeight;

            document.querySelector(".Approach--timeline svg").setAttribute("style", "transform: scaleY(" + Math.floor(convertRange( (offset + wheight), [objectMin, objectMax], [0, 1.0]) * 100) / 100 + ")");
        }
    }

    window.addEventListener('scroll', function(){
        requestAnimationFrame(animateLine)
    });
}
```

As you can see it's jumpy it doesn't scroll at 60fps, altho I'm using the scale attribute, requestAnimationFrame and rounded values. Any idea what a better way of implementing this animation is? Preferably without jQuery. GSAP is okay since I'm already running it.

Comment: Why use an SVG? Why not use a regular div and animate height with CSS?

Comment: Cause right now I'm using just a simple line for demo purposes, but the svg will be a bit more complex later on. This is just the base and I will be adding some circles!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you add a `transition` time to make it work more smoothly?

```
.Approach--timeline svg {
    transition: .5s ease;
}
```

```js
window.requestAnimationFrame = window.requestAnimationFrame || window.mozRequestAnimationFrame || window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame || window.msRequestAnimationFrame || function(f){setTimeout(f, 1000/60)}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    Timeline();
});

function Timeline() {
 requestAnimationFrame(animateLine)
  
    function convertRange( value, r1, r2 ) { 
        return ( value - r1[ 0 ] ) * ( r2[ 1 ] - r2[ 0 ] ) / ( r1[ 1 ] - r1[ 0 ] ) + r2[ 0 ];
    }

    function animateLine() {
        var offset = window.scrollY;
        var wheight = window.innerHeight;
        var timeline = document.querySelector(".Approach--steps");
        var theight = timeline.getBoundingClientRect().top - wheight;
        
        if (theight < 0) {
            var timelineMin = timeline.offsetHeight;
            var objectMin = timeline.offsetTop;
            var objectMax = timeline.offsetTop + timeline.offsetHeight;

            document.querySelector(".Approach--timeline svg").setAttribute("style", "transform: scaleY(" + Math.floor(convertRange( (offset + wheight), [objectMin, objectMax], [0, 1.0]) * 100) / 100 + ")");
        }
    }

    window.addEventListener('scroll', function(){
        requestAnimationFrame(animateLine)
    });
}
```

```css
.Approach--steps {
  margin-top: 600px;
  margin-bottom: 200px
}

.Approach--header {
    margin-top: 80px;
}

.Approach--step {
    margin-top: 500px;
    padding-left: 56px;
}

.Approach--timeline {

}

.Approach--timeline svg {
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: -100px;
    height: 100%;
    width: 4px;
    transition: .5s ease;
    transform: scaleY(0);
    transform-origin: top left;
}

.Approach--steps {
    position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="Approach--steps">
   <div class="Approach--timeline">
      <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 1 1" preserveAspectRatio="none">
          <linearGradient id="grad" x1="0%" y1="0%" x2="0%" y2="100%" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
              <stop stop-color="#22D9BC" stop-opacity="1.0" offset="0%" />
              <stop stop-color="#1674F5" stop-opacity="1.0" offset="50%" />
              <stop stop-color="#7D00FF" stop-opacity="1.0" offset="100%" />
          </linearGradient>
          <rect x="0" y="0" width="1" height="1" fill="url(#grad)" id="Approach--svg" />
      </svg>
  </div>
  
  <div class="Approach--step">
      <p>1. Khaled Ipsum</p>
      <p>Lorem Khaled Ipsum is a major key to success. Eliptical talk. How’s business? Boomin. They will try to close the door on you, just open it. You see the hedges, how I got it shaped up? It’s important to shape up your hedges, it’s like getting a haircut, stay fresh. Wraith talk. We don’t see them, we will never see them. Life is what you make it, so let’s make it. Another one. Hammock talk come soon. It’s important to use cocoa butter. It’s the key to more success, why not live smooth? Why live rough?</p>
  </div>

  <div class="Approach--step">
      <p>2. Lion</p>
      <p>The ladies always say Khaled you smell good, I use no cologne. Cocoa butter is the key. Hammock talk come soon. Put it this way, it took me twenty five years to get these plants, twenty five years of blood sweat and tears, and I’m never giving up, I’m just getting started. Major key, don’t fall for the trap, stay focused. It’s the ones closest to you that want to see you fail. The key to success is to keep your head above the water, never give up.</p>
  </div>

  <div class="Approach--step">
      <p>3. We the best</p>
  </div>
  
  
</div>
```

Comment: This would be enough. Also it's not that the FPS is low. It's just that when you scroll the window doesn't go through every pixel smoothly. So the svg will be jumpy because the scroll is jumpy. So just adding a transition will fix it.

Comment: Heya. That's a simple solution and it even works. My Javascript might be better than I thought.

Answer (score -1):

[Here's a gist](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/14e09c65e4f297325c6056e967e8439f) of a working GSAP example.

You mentioned you plan on adding other elements to your SVG. I would recommend you read the GSAP/SVG docs [here](https://greensock.com/svg-tips).

When animating with GSAP, I'd pretty much always recommend using an ID selector.

Comment: This keeps the FPS / lag issue alive. The only thing that's done now is instead of scaleY we got GSAP integration, which doesn't really matter. I personally think the convertRange function is requiring too much from my browser to handle the animation with 60FPS.

Comment: Choosing to bandaid the problem with a CSS transition is a bad choice! Good luck.